# Javascript code not working in contact form

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7

I want to create a function in my contact form 7 where if a user selects a specific item from a dropdown a form field appears in the form. After some tinkering I came up with some code:

```
[text* your-name placeholder"Volledige naam" ]


    [email* your-email placeholder"Geldig emailadres"]


    [select* your-type id:TypeDropdown placeholder"Selecteer soort" "Algemene vraag" "Afspraak maken" "Klacht indienen"]


    [text* your-subject placeholder"Onderwerp"] 

    [date* your-date id:EnterDate]

    [textarea your-message placeholder="Uw bericht"]

[submit "Verzenden"]

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("EnterDate").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("TypeDropdown").addEventListener("change", displayDateField);
function displayDateField() {
  var dropdownText = document.getElementById("TypeDropdown").value;
  if (dropdownText === "Afspraak maken") {
    document.getElementByid("EnterDate").style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("EnterDate").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Except when I try this code it doesn't work. The new form field *EnterDate* does not appear in the form.

Any idea if it's because of a flaw in my code or if this just isn't possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding conditional logic group in form instead of using javascript. Have a look at this link

https://conditional-fields-cf7.bdwm.be/conditional-fields-for-contact-form-7-tutorial/